# Why does X @ coef_ + intercept_ does not equal Y_pred for sklearn PLSRegression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, partial-least-squares

I performed partial least squares regression using Python's sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression using the example data in the sklearn docs. I am surprised that X @ coef_ + intercept_ does not equal Y_pred. Can someone please explain?

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
X = [[0., 0., 1.], [1.,0.,0.], [2.,2.,2.], [2.,5.,4.]]
Y = [[0.1, -0.2], [0.9, 1.1], [6.2, 5.9], [11.9, 12.3]]
pls2 = PLSRegression(n_components=2)
pls2.fit(X, Y)
PLSRegression()
Y_pred = pls2.predict(X)
```

```
X@pls2.coef_ + pls2.intercept_
```

returns

```
array([[ 6.80991986,  6.88073249],
       [ 6.24687317,  6.24590503],
       [16.37620337, 16.72659034],
       [27.32746904, 28.13552828]])
```

but `Y_pred` is

```
array([[ 0.26087869,  0.15302213],
       [ 0.60667302,  0.45634164],
       [ 6.46856199,  6.48931562],
       [11.7638863 , 12.00132061]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to center and scale your `X` matrix before multiplying by the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-learn is open-source, so you always can [check the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb24/sklearn/cross_decomposition/_pls.py#L472)

```py
        # Normalize
        X -= self._x_mean
        X /= self._x_std
        # TODO(1.3): change `self._coef_` to `self.coef_`
        Ypred = X @ self._coef_.T
        return Ypred + self.intercept_
```

where

```py
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        [...]
        return self._coef_.T
```

Comment: thats exactly what I did to give my answer :)